# Grunt-uglify recursively

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have a set of subfolders with some *.dev.js files. I need grunt to uglify those and create the uglified files next to the source files, for each .dev.js file in the directory tree. 
Here is how I try to do it:

```
uglify: {
  options: {
    banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n'
  },
  dist: {
    files: {
      src: '/folder/**/*.dev.js',
      ext: '.js',
      flatten: true,
      expand: true
    }
  }
}
```

But this gives an error:

> Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
>   File src created: 13.49 kB → 5.62 kB
>
> > Destination ext not written because src files were empty.
> >     Warning: Object true has no method 'indexOf' Use --force to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your question because I had the same issue, the answer for every one else that see this (like me) is:

- You are using "src: '/folder/**/*.dev.js'"
- The error is in the first slash (/folder), grunt/nodejs is looking in the folder "folder" in the root of your drive instead in your app root (for example c:\folder or OSX\folder).
- The solution is to remove the first slash or use a dot before the slash ".\folder", the complete solution should be:

  ```
  uglify: {
    options: {
      banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n'
    },
    dist: {
      files: [{
        src: './folder/**/*.dev.js',
        ext: '.js',
        flatten: true,
        expand: true
      }]
    }
  }
  ```

Also, don't ask me why I just learn about grunt 1 hour ago, you need to but the files value inside a javascript array [{ }] (not just the curly braces), isolating the "files" object looks like this:

```
    files: [{
      src: './folder/**/*.dev.js',
      ext: '.js',
      flatten: true,
      expand: true
    }]
```